# eBay API to get Total Amount using GetOrders by PHP

Tags: php, ebay-api

Right now, I am using GetOrders to launch all my orders to my database. Normally, it works fine. I can get the total amount(includes item price and tax) by using:

> [`$totalAmount = $order->AmountPaid;`](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getorders.html#Response.OrderArray.Order.AmountPaid)

However, when I tried to import an International Order, the amount was wrong.

[image]

The thing is: I only charged him $102.90, but the amount here gives me $157.62

Does anyone know how can I get the total price, which under the "Total" column, in eBay? What kind of value I need to use? Or maybe how to calculate the price for international order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There few fields related to order price

**OrderArray.Order.AmountPaid**

> This value indicates the total amount of the order. This amount includes the sale price of each line item, shipping and handling charges, shipping insurance (if offered and selected by the buyer), additional services, and any applied sales tax. This value is returned after the buyer has completed checkout (the CheckoutStatus.Status output field reads 'Complete').

**OrderArray.Order.Total**

> The Total amount equals the Subtotal value plus the shipping/handling, shipping insurance, and sales tax costs.

**OrderArray.Order.Subtotal**

> The subtotal amount for the order is the total cost of all order line items. This value does not include any shipping/handling, shipping insurance, or sales tax costs.

I would suggest you try Order.Total for receive price of the order.

Comment: At the end, I choose to use Subtotal. Cause I still got some issues when I use Total. Thank you~